# No display after installing new GPU

Tags: gpu, compatibility, nvidia-geforce

CPU Model: Dell Optiplex 990 Tower I7-2600
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050

After inserting the new card and rebooting, I was unfortunately met with a static "No signal" screen.
I ensured the VGA cable was still plugged in. As was the gpu firmly mantled in place, with fans spinning as it warmed.
Upon removing the GPU windows booted normally.
In the device manager was the GTX 1050, in Hidden devices. Not functioning because it was now removed.

What I've tried:
Booting with both the default BIOS settings, and the 'Enable PCI Slot' option disabled. Disabling hyper threading.

Booting in safe mode, minimal drivers.

In desperation, inserting the GPU after the PC booted, so I could at least have a screen. (There were no observable consequences) and again tried to install the driver with the disc, to be told there was still no graphics card present, as the fans spun. Needless to say, a following reboot displayed the same blank screen.

It took 2 weeks to ship, so I'd prefer replacement as a last resort.

Comment: It is a *very* bad idea to insert or remove PCI cards while the computer is running. PCI is only hot swappable on specialized hardware. The computer not only has to deal with the DMA implications, but the bus itself wasn't electrically designed to be hot swap. You could break your motherboard or GPU doing this!

Answer (score 0):

Some bios have options for selecting a default graphics adapters. Make sure that you've set this to prioritize the PCI-e slot over an integrated adapter.